# plpgsql syntx error at $$

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a function with plpgsql for some reason i'm getting a syntax error at `$$ language plpgsql;`

This is the func i'm writing:

```
create or replace function hello() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if new.my_sc!= null and new.his_sc!= null
    then update people p 
    set p.score=p.score+1 
    where p.id = new.id;
end if;
return null;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

my Trigger:

```
after insert on game
execute procedure hello();
```

my syntax error comes in at the last line.
any idea?
Thankx

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql here?

Comment: what about `end;` after `return null;`? ;-)

Comment: @JosMac lol that worked i'm new with this Thanks!

Comment: Proper indentation makes sense!!!

Comment: @JosMac you think you can help me? my function does not seem to update or do anything to the lines but it runs.

Comment: try this: `if new.my_sc is not null and new.his_sc in not null` - this is the only way how test for NULL really works in pg

Comment: + specify `FOR EACH ROW` in trigger because default is `STATEMENT` and in such a case you cannot access OLD/ NEW values.

Comment: but I would like to use just the newest record inserted

Comment: do i have to use a timestamp?

Comment: Your `begin` has no `end;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name fixed that! thanks

Comment: I think i figured everything out! Thanks all!!!